# Jquery Mobile Stops Nav Links

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm integrating jquery mobile into my site now.  But when I add the script for the library it breaks all of my navigation links.  I know it is calling ajax requests somehow...but I'm not sure what is happening exactly.  I pushed to github so you can see.  Locally I get a different error than I do on github when a click a nav link.  My local error is:

```
 "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Ryan/Desktop/Ryan%20Drive-Laptop/Web%20Design/Websites/Jessica/contact.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. index.html:1"
```

Here is the site on github if you need to check out any code:

http://ryan8765.github.io/jessica/portrait.html

Thanks.

Comment: disable Ajax if you don't want jQM to load pages via Ajax. But you'll lose animated transition between pages.

Comment: Omar, so if you didn't want to lose animated transitions....is there some other way of correcting this issue?

Comment: It's difficult to know without code. Please add details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the Cross origin policy which is implemented into the W3C standard for browsers
https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

You will have to tell your server to

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

I hope this helped

EDIT:

after double checking I see your are trying to load a file://...
Try doing the same thing in Mozilla ;)